# Ragged array not showing all averages

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

It only prints out the average to the first column but doesn't do anything for the next.
it only prints out 717, for the first column average. It is a ragged array. Everything else compiles fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Fitness
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int [][] week = {{800,1000,100},{450,100,845,20,1200,200},{1800,250,400},{0,1500,800,120},{600,500},{700,1400,1700,100},{675}};
    System.out.println("Average over 7 days");
    avgCalb(week);      
   static void avgCalb(int [][] x)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++)
      {
        int colTotal = 0;
          for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
          colTotal = colTotal + x[i][j];

      }
          System.out.println(colTotal/7);
          break;
      }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Why did you put that "break;" statement there? It breaks your loop after the first column.

Comment: because if not itll give me an array index out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

summing columns

```
static void avgCalb(int [][] x)
{
  int[] colTotal = new int[x.length];
  for(int j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < x[j].length; i++)
    {
      colTotal[i] += x[j][i]

    }
  }

  for(int i = 0;i<colTotal.length;i++) {
    System.out.println((double)colTotal[i]/colTotal.length);
  }
}
```

summing rows

```
static void avgCalb(int [][] x)
{

  for(int j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
  {
    int colTotal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x[j].length; i++)
    {
      colTotal += x[j][i];

    }
    System.out.println(colTotal/x[j].length);
  }

}
```

Comment: It still doesn't show all the other columns averages. I have to add all the columns then get the each individual average. The divided by 7 was for everyday of the week

Comment: Sorry, i copied your "break" accidentally

Comment: Your code adds all the rows, I need to add the columns

Comment: Edited. You can refer to the section which sum the columns